# More then one SQL Windows with the same session in PL'SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, plsqldeveloper

I'm new to PL/SQL Developer and have session problems.

Everytime I open an SQL file, Developer opens a new session to the database.
I have a limit of 2 sessions, so I can't open more then 2 SQL files at the same time.

I would like to open as many SQL files as I want with the same session.

Does PL/SQL Developer have settings for this somewhere?

I couldn't find it in Preferences but I hope there is one.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the menu Tools/Preferences "Oracle Connection" chose "Session Mode" `Single session` or `Dual session`.

And restart plsql developer.

Comment: Thank you! I assumed that means how many database I can connect to, so I didn't give it a try.